# How do I track if a user has visited 10+ times in a month?

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

How do I track if a user has visited my application 10+ times in last 30 days? I am fairly new to Google Analytics. I have already registered and set up my tracking code, and normal page tracks are registered, but how do I get this type of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think GA can provide how many times a registered user of your site visited it. You may need to do it yourself.

Create a table to track `UserVists` which stores the `UserId`, `LoginDate`, `IPAddress`. Whenever your user login succesfully to your site, add an entry to this table. Now you have the data in the table and you can do whatever analysis you want (30 days / 1 week /1 year ...)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do this in GA, although you can get the % of returning traffic vs. new traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom report with a metric of “unique visitors” (or a custom variable you may have assigned to specific users) and a dimension drilldown of “count of visits”.  Then filter the report to only include count of visits greater than 9.

I don’t think this is exactly what you’re looking for, but at least it should tell you how many visitors have visited 10+ times within the selected timeframe.